# Using a for loop to find the biggest number in an array

Tags: javascript

I've asked this question before but I forgot a key detail. I have to use a for-loop to figure to find the answer. I dont understand why my code is not working, when I read it logically I feel that it should work, but what it does is return 3,4,2 as opposed to the highest number of the 3 (i.e. 4)

```
const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4

for(items of array2){
    if(items > 0) {
        console.log(Math.max(items));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What have I misinterpreted? Please dont just give me the answer, explain why your way works and mine does not! Thank you

Comment: *" I have to use a for-loop..."* but in your code you're using a `for .. of` loop! What loop you should use ?

Comment: It does'nt matter what loop it is as long as its a for... loop

Comment: Technically, there's a huge difference...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ["a", 3, 5, 8, 100, 20];

let max = Math.max(...arr.filter(e => typeof e !== "string"));

console.log(max);
```

OR

```js
let arr = ["a", 3, 5, 8, 100, 20];

let max;

for (item of arr) {
  if (typeof item != "string") {
    if (max) {
      if (max < item) max = item;
    } else {
      max = item;
    }
  }
}


console.log(max);
```

Comment: Hey, I understand how it would work with a filter and the typeOf method, but the task is to use a for loop? 

Do you know how to do it with a for loop and how?

Comment: Look again I edited

Comment: Okay, am I correct in saying that what your doing is storing the next index into the max variable. if the next iterable is bigger than the current max variable then store it in the max variable. else if it is equal to the next iterable do nothing?

Comment: max stores the current maximum value

Answer (score 1):

If you NEED to use a loop, then u shouldn't use `Math.max()` as it takes an undefined list of parameters (not an array, and no other types than numbers).
You can still manage to filter the array beforehand or check the type.

The error you do is that you use the function `Math.max()` in a loop that already "works as a loop"

Here is the spec :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

A simple way to do a loop is :

```
max = 0
for(item in array2){
    if(item>max){
        max=item
    }
}
console.log(max)
```

edit: you can check with typeof to avoid errors and initiate the value of max with -Infinity or else you can't get the max out of negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4
    let max = -Infinity
    for(items of array2){
        if (typeof items == "string") continue;
        if(items > max) {
            max = items
    }}
    console.log(max)
```

Your method isn't working because in your for loops, items is each element of the array. So calling Math.max on 3 will return 3 and on 4 will return 4

Comment: What about `arr = [-3, -2, -10]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue: the `Math.max` needs more than 1 parameter!

The bad solution: filter to get only `number`, the `spread` the result array as params of `Math.max`. 3 times O(N).

Simple solution: write your own `findMax` function:

```js
const findMax = (arr) => {
    let max = -Infinity;
    for(let i of arr){
        if(typeof(i) === 'number' && i > max)
            max = i
    }
    return max;
}

findMax(['a', 3, 4, 2])
```